# MVC does not return Readonly Properties via Submit Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit, readonly, antiforgerytoken

It has been some time i try figuring out this!
Generally: i want to get a "Readonly, Hidden" Property from my Form.

I Trimmed all that is unncessey from the example:
i have the following Model

```
public class ChangeOrderDetailModel
{
...
...
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

and in the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitChangeOrder", "Order"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()<br/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.OrderId) <br />
...
...
}
```

Now:

1. in the View HTML, there is a hidden field for OrderID...
2. I dont want anyone to change "OrderID" cause it can cause security issues.
3. I need the OrderID number at the form submit...
4. **Problem** When the form is submitted to the Controller
   `OrderController.SubmitChangeOrder(ChangeOrderDetailModel mdl){}`
   i see that `mdl.OrderID` **is always = 0**.
5. When I remove the `ReadOnly(true)` attribute from the propertie, everything works ok, but anyone can change the value of the field using simple JS, which is VERY BAD.
   and i dont want to relay only on a hash token cause it is easly broken too :(

Why is it working like this?
Am i missing something, a better way to achive what i like?

*note: there might be several change orders going on in parallel so session is kinda problematic.*

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Readonly(true)] you are explicitly instructing the model binder not to bind the field to the property of the model. By rendering the property using `Html.HiddenFor` have already achieved what you want in your rendered html. You can include a second parameter in your controller action as `int OrderId` and the model binder will bind the value on to that variable

A rogue user may still be able to edit OrderId. One way to guard it against such action is to encrypt OrderId and use the encrypted value in the model and subsequently on the page. Then once the postback happens, you will decrypt the encrypted OrderId. Encryption and decryption could be encapsulated in to the model itself

@TomerW, if I understood your question correctly, your core issue is that a rogue user can change the value of OrderId at the client side, My suggestion is not to render OrderId in its bare form, but encrypt it at the server side using a key only known at the server. You should render the encrypted value in HTML as a hidden filed. A rogue user may still attempt to change the associated value, but decryption will fail and you will know that someone has tried to fiddle with your value. Following is a stub implementation,

```
public class ChangeOrderDetailModel
{
    [ReadOnly(true)] /*You are instructing the model binder not to bind this value*/
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    private string _OrderIdEnc;
    public string OrderIdEnc
    {
        /*Encryp*/
        get
        {
            return Encrypt(OrderId);
        }

        set
        {
            _OrderIdEnc = value;
        }
    }

    public void DecryptPayload()
    {
        /* Decrypt, and this will fail is someone has edited the value */
        OrderId = Decrypt(_OrderIdEnc);
    }
}
```

In your view model, use `@Html.HiddenFor(o => o. OrderIdEnc)`. You can use standard windows crypto to do the encryption and decryption.

To be extremely safe, you can use a different key for each req/response session. This will prevent a more advanced rogue user from replacing OrderIdEnc with an older version.

I am sure that there may be other solutions, but above is a pattern that I have used many times and has worked

Cheers

Comment: do you have a link where i can see an example for this ?
i dont get how you plan to use the encrypted values.

Comment: ok, i see what needs to be done,  i should call DecryptPayload() at Server side validation of the form...
thank you, btw: you know any automation for this? might be useful to implement such verification?

Comment: @Tomer W; Since DecrtptPayload is a located on the model, it could be potentially called from the controller action and/or from validation. I would also vote for your choice of calling it from the validator as it is the most suitable to perform such a task. I didn’t quite what you meant by ‘automation’ in this particular context. If you are looking for a pattern, then you may create an interface to serialize and  encrypt the complete module and de-serialize back at validation, but may become an overkill. ASP.net web forms do just this with view state